# Append a variable in ROR using Javascript or Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Excuse me for very dumb question, I am very new to Ruby On Rails. Am trying to Create a mockup of a page, the page has two Views, Product View One and Product View Two. There is a small Content Variation in two views, Trying to achieve it through setting a variable product_view_one = true or false.

Now my question is

1. How to append a variable in ROR using Javascript or Ajax?

Below is the code..

```html
<% product_view_one = [true].sample %>
<table class="table table-hover table-line">
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th colspan="<%= product_view_one ? "5" : "4" %>">        
    <ul class="nav nav-pills"> 
      <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <%= rand(1..20) %> Published </a></li>
      <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <%= rand(1..8) %> Dtafts </a></li> 
      <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <%= rand(1..8) %> Expired </a></li> 
    </ul>
  </th>

  <th colspan="2">
    <ul class="pagination">  <!— View Change —>
      <li><a href=“#” onClick ="changeProductView ()"> Product View One </a></li> <!— 
      <li><a href=“#” onClick ="changeProductView ()"> Product View Two </a></li>
    </ul>
  </th>

</tr>

<tr>
  <th class="title">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  </th>

  <th> 
    <%= product_view_one ? "Users" : "" %>
  </th>

  <th>
    <%= product_view_one ? "Group" : "Audience" %> 
  </th>

  <th>
    Updates
  </th>

  <% if !product_view_one %>
  <th>
    Expiration
  </th>
  <% end %>

  <th>Published</th>

  <th class="icons"></th>

</tr>

</thead>
<tbody>

<% 10.times do |i| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/mockups/course/index.html"><%= Faker::Lorem.words(rand(2..5)).join(' ').capitalize %></a>

      <% if product_view_one %>
        <!-- tags -->
        <ul class="media-tags">
          <% [1, 2, 3, 4].sample.times do %>
          <li class="media-tag media-tag-default"><%= ["Service", "UX", "Wireframes", "Misc"].sample %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    </td>

    <td> 
      <% if !product_view_one %>
      <!-- tags -->
      <ul class="media-tags">
        <% [1, 2, 3, 4].sample.times do %>
        <li class="media-tag media-tag-default"><%= ["Service", "UX", "Wireframes", "Misc"].sample %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
      <% else %>
        <ul> 
          <% rand(1..9).times do %>
            <li> <%= Faker::Name.first_name %>, </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    </td>

    <% if product_view_one %>
    <td> 
      <ul> 
        <% rand(1..9).times do %>
          <li> <%= Faker::Name.first_name %>, </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <% end %>

    <% if !product_view_one %>
    <td >
      <a class="views-views report-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <% if [true, false, false].sample %>
          <%= rand(1..999) %> 
        <% else %>
          <%= rand(1..9) %> 
        <% end %>
      </a>
    </td>
    <% end %>

    <td >
      <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);"> 
        <% if [true, false, false].sample %>
          <%= rand(1..28) %> <%= ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"].sample %> by <%= Faker::Name.first_name %>
        <% else %>
          <%= "-" %>
        <% end %>
      </a>
    </td>

    <% if !product_view_one %>
    <td >
      <span class="" ><%= rand(1..150) %> days </span>
    </td>
    <% end %>

    <td>
       Oct 28
    </td>

    <td class="action-btn">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs"><i class="icon icon-trash-o"></i></a>
    </td>   

  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>

<!— jQuery Code to set the variable —>

<script>
$("#prodViewOne").click(function () {
 var prod_view_one = true ;
});

$("#prodViewTwo").click(function () {
 var prod_view_one = false ;
});
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "appending a variable"?

Comment: I Mean passing a Variable from JS to ROR.

Comment: I would need a litte more insight into you're controller and the problem to make my answer more accurate. If you are doing this in Ruby on Rails, you would want to push that variable and it's logic down into the controller and present two seperate views (possible using a similar partial view with different locals passed to it).

Otherwise, if you are going for a more interactive experience (eg: the user clicks edit and text labels change to text inputs), you will need something like EmberJS to provide two-way binding.

That's not to say you can't do it all in javascript,but it would be tedious

Comment: You are aware that ROR runs _only on the server_ and JS runs _only on the browser_, right?

Comment: You can't pass the variable itself from JS to Ruby. But you can pass its value, using AJAX call.

Comment: Thank you Ice, Uri Agassi and Grych.